# Считывание из Google-таблиц в Json

Tags: javascript, json, google-spreadsheet

Есть сайт, написанный с помощью генератора assemble.io. Контент статический, хранится в json. Я хочу сделать, чтобы контент брался с Google-таблиц. Нашла отличный пример [Experimenting with google spreadsheets, assemble.io and internationalisation](http://jestersimpps.github.io/experimenting-with-google-spreadsheets-assemble-io-and-internationalisation/), всё работает. Но он работает только с простыми данными ключ-значение:

```
"name1" : "value1",
"name2" : "value2",
...
```

Не понятно, как сделать, чтобы он мог брать из таблиц и данные в виде массивов, типа:

```
"name" : [ "value1", "value2" ... ]
```

Скорее всего, потребуется модифицировать [вот этот файл](https://github.com/theoephraim/grunt-i18n-gspreadsheet/blob/master/tasks/i18n_gspreadsheet.js#L138).

Answer (score 1):

раз нет ответов, приведу небольшой хак

```js
let getArr = () => ['a', 'b', 'c']
let str = getArr.toString()
console.log(`typeof str: ${typeof str}`); //typeof str: string
console.log(str); //() => ['a', 'b', 'c']

let arr = eval(`(${str})()`)
console.log(`arr instanceof Array: ${arr instanceof Array}`); //arr instanceof Array: true
console.log(arr); //(3) ["a", "b", "c"]
```

и помним, что `eval` считается небезобасным

**upd:**
да, в большинстве случаев достаточно

- `JSON.stringify()`
- `JSON.parse()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON